# Detect if build target is installed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

I maintain an editor extension called Build Automator and I wanted to upgrade it so that it would disable any platforms that the user does not have installed; I did some searching through the docs but couldn't find anything.

I was wondering if there's any way to detect if a module is installed, or if a build target exists?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a public API for it. But of course you can still get there with a bit of reflection. Whether or not you should go there depends on how reliable you want things to be.

The BuildPipeline has the following static method

```
internal static extern bool IsBuildTargetSupported(BuildTarget target);
```

You could invoke it as follows:

```
MethodInfo buildTargetSupported = typeof(BuildPipeline).GetMethod("IsBuildTargetSupported", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if(Convert.ToBoolean(buildTargetSupported.Invoke(null, new object[] { BuildTarget.PS4 })))
{
    Debug.Log("PS4 Supported");
}
if (Convert.ToBoolean(buildTargetSupported.Invoke(null, new object[] { BuildTarget.Android })))
{
    Debug.Log("Android Supported");
}
//etc
```

It's not great, and if there is a public API I have overlooked, you should definitely use that. But in a pinch it may do.

Comment: This is definitely less of an "official" solution than I was thinking of but yeah it seems like it should work. You mentioned reliability, can you see this code not working properly at times?

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be getting errors for MethodInfo, BindingFlags and Convert

Comment: You'll have to add `using System;`and `using System.Reflection;` And as for "not working" ... whenever they decide to change their internals, you'll have to adapt. It's not an "official" way to do it via a public API. But then again, I don't expect changes any time soon.

Comment: I get this error
`TargetParameterCountException: parameters do not match signature`
Also, is something similar to do for BuildTargetGroup? as a second layer of checking

Comment: What version of Unity are you on? I was on 5.5.1p3. And .net 2.0 or subset?

Comment: 5.6, and it's an editor script, so is there any way to change .net 2.0 or subset?

Comment: I don't have the beta installed here, so I'll have to look later. But you can inspect the DLL yourself with ILSpy or something like that to find the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that Unity has made this method public i e: [BuildPipeline.IsTargetPlatformSupported](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.IsBuildTargetSupported.html)